# GoogleMock SaveArg for saving array? Compiler throwing errors, and I don't see a good solution yet

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

First, I already put up a [post at the relevant google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/googlemock/3vWB7WP2UJM/discussion), but I'm not sure how active that is. Anyway, here's my problem:

Suppose I have a class Alpha that has a member Beta. (specifically, a pointer to Beta is injected at construction); Beta is some object that will be mocked out later. But we care about what, precisely, Alpha calls when it calls a function from beta.

```
class Gamma{
private:
    char array[15];
public:
    char* getArray() { return &array[0]; }
}

class Alpha{
private:
    Beta* m_beta;
public:
    Alpha(Beta* external) : m_beta(external) {}

    DoStuff(const Gamma& thing){
        // ... maybe do some stuff with Gamma;
        Beta->Function(thing.getArray(), 15);
    }
};

class Beta{
public:
    virtual void Function(const char* array, int sizeOfArray);
};

class MockBeta : public Beta{
    MOCK_METHOD2(Function, void(const char*, int));
}

using ::testing::_;

Test(AlphaTest, DoStuffTest){
    char expectedArray[15] = {/*whatever*/};
    char actualArray[15];
//    char* arrayPtr = nullptr;

    MockBeta mock_external;
    Alpha testObject(&mock_external);

    EXPECT_CALL(mock_external, Function(_,_))
      .WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&(&actualArray[0]));
//      .WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&arrayPtr));
}
```

This example complains on compile: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'char *' (on the line:  .WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&(&actualArray[0])); )

I've tried a variety of approaches.

- A custom Action with parameter:  ACTION_P(SaveToPtr, ptr) { ptr = arg0; } doesn't work because ptr is a const value for the custom actions.
- Instead of an array, I could try with just a general char*. But then it gives a compiler error that it's incomatible with type 'const char *const'

And probably other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, in posting the question, I think I found my own answer. The key is in the `DoStuff(const Gamma& thing)` signature. If Gamma is const, then the function can't actually `// ... maybe do some stuff with Gamma`. But if Gamma isn't const, then, if we assume Gamma is unit tested, whatever non-const functions we'd call to it should already be tested and we'd know what the result of Gamma::getArray() would be in such a case.

Comment: Though your answer and thoughts are presented a bit addleheaded and unclear, I appreciate you solved your problem, and posted an answer yourself. Using GoogleMock, it often forces you to have better interface designs.